Turn off indicator with if else statement in Pine script
I added 4 indicators in a pine script and changed a bit based on my requirements but I want an option to turn one or more indicator off via indicator settings. So I created if statement with curly braces {} and thought it would work like in PHP but it didn't.
I then tried pine script documentation and put plot functions in if section but I keep getting error that "Cannot use 'plot' in local scop". Please help. I don't know how to accomplish this task now.
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle="BB+VWAP", title="BB+VWAP", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

// Indicator ON/OFF
indicatorBB  = input.string("ON", title="Bollinger Band", options = ["ON", "OFF"])
indicatorEMA = input.string("ON", title="EMA", options = ["ON", "OFF"])


// Bollinger Band
length = input.int(20, minval=1, group="BB Settings")
src1 = input(hlc3, title="Source", group="BB Settings")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev", group="BB Settings")
basis = ta.sma(src1, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src1, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset1 = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500, group="BB Settings")

if (indicatorBB == "ON")
    plot(basis, "BB Basis", color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 80), offset = offset1, display = display.none)
    p1 = plot(upper, "BB Upper", color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 70), offset = offset1)
    p2 = plot(lower, "BB Lower", color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 70), offset = offset1)
    fill(p1, p2, title = "BB Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))


// EMA
firstema = input.int(10, title="EMA 1", group="EMA Settings")
secondema = input.int(20, title="EMA 2", group="EMA Settings")
thirdema = input.int(50, title="EMA 3", group="EMA Settings")
fourthema = input.int(100, title="EMA 4", group="EMA Settings")
fifthema = input.int(200, title="EMA 5", group="EMA Settings")

EMA1 = ta.ema(close, firstema)
EMA2 = ta.ema(close, secondema)
EMA3 = ta.ema(close, thirdema)
EMA4 = ta.ema(close, fourthema)
EMA5 = ta.ema(close, fifthema)

if (indicatorEMA == "ON")
    plotEMA1 = plot(EMA1, color=color.rgb(41, 98, 255, 0), linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")
    plotEMA2 = plot(EMA2, color=color.rgb(245, 124, 0, 50), linewidth=2, title="EMA 2")
    plot(EMA3, color=color.rgb(41, 98, 255, 70), linewidth=2, title="EMA 3", display = display.none)
    plot(EMA4, color=color.rgb(41, 98, 255, 70), linewidth=2, title="EMA 4", display = display.none)
    plot(EMA5, color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 40), linewidth=2, title="EMA 5")


This is not how Pine works, as you just realized. In regular programming languages we are used to make a selection (IF) and then do something if that turned to be True (thereby saving resources when it is False).
In Pine if you cannot use something in a local scope, you have to "bring forward" the condition your IF relies on.
This won't work:
if (indicatorEMA == "ON")
   plotEMA1 = plot(EMA1, color=color.rgb(41, 98, 255, 0), linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")

So move the conditional into the plot and draw the plot on every candle with some trick. We will color the plot based on the condition:
plotEMA1 = plot(EMA1, color = indicatorEMA == "ON" ? color.rgb(41, 98, 255, 0) : na, linewidth=2, title="EMA 1")

I used a ternary operator so when the condition is true, we plot with normal color but when it is false, we color with na (which is a Pineish NIL) and that will not display anything (and will not garble the chart with invalid data).
A nicer (and simpler) solution, create 4 boolean input variables and use those variables instead of that indicatorEMA == "ON". If you create those variables with grouping and inline features, you will get 4 nice checkboxes in the Indicator settings.

Thanks for answering. Although this makes them transparent so indicator lines won't show on chart but it leaves selector white dots (not sure if these are called that) all over the chart. Not exactly what I am looking for.

I have provided your code with some modifications to make it work.

**// Indicator ON/OFF**

indicatorBB  = input.bool(true, title="Show/Hide Bollinger Band")
indicatorEMA = input.bool(true, title="Show/Hide EMA")
showemafill = input.bool(false, title="Show/Hide EMA BG color fill")

// Bollinger Band

length = input.int(20, minval=1, group="BB Settings")
src1 = input(hlc3, title="Source", group="BB Settings")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev", group="BB Settings")
basis = ta.sma(src1, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src1, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset1 = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500, group="BB Settings")


plot(basis, "BB Basis", color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 80), offset = offset1, display = indicatorBB ? display.all : display.none)
p1 = plot(upper, "BB Upper", color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 70), offset = offset1, display = indicatorBB ? display.all : display.none)
p2 = plot(lower, "BB Lower", color=color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 70), offset = offset1, display = indicatorBB ? display.all : display.none)
fill(p1, p2, title = "BB Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95), display = indicatorBB ? display.all : display.none)


// EMA
firstema = input.int(10, title="EMA 1", group="EMA Settings")
secondema = input.int(20, title="EMA 2", group="EMA Settings")
thirdema = input.int(50, title="EMA 3", group="EMA Settings")
fourthema = input.int(100, title="EMA 4", group="EMA Settings")
fifthema = input.int(200, title="EMA 5", group="EMA Settings")

EMA1 = ta.ema(close, firstema)
EMA2 = ta.ema(close, secondema)
EMA3 = ta.ema(close, thirdema)
EMA4 = ta.ema(close, fourthema)
EMA5 = ta.ema(close, fifthema)

plotEMA1 = plot(EMA1, color=color.rgb(41, 98, 255, 0), linewidth=2, title="EMA 1", display = indicatorEMA ? display.all : display.none)
plotEMA2 = plot(EMA2, color=color.rgb(245, 124, 0, 50), linewidth=2, title="EMA 2", display = indicatorEMA ? display.all : display.none)
plot(EMA3, color=#1752f2d1, linewidth=3, title="EMA 3", display = indicatorEMA ? display.all : display.none)
plot(EMA4, color=#2842884d, linewidth=4, title="EMA 4", display = indicatorEMA ? display.all : display.none)
plot(EMA5, color=#1dd62399, linewidth=4, title="EMA 5", display = indicatorEMA ? display.all : display.none)


//Additional Fill color 
ema_fill_color = color.white
if (EMA5>EMA1 and EMA5>EMA2 and EMA5>EMA3 )
    ema_fill_color :=  color.new(color.orange,70) 
else if (EMA1>EMA3 and EMA1>EMA4 and EMA1>EMA5 ) 
    ema_fill_color := color.new(color.lime,70)

// you can add additional conditions and the respective colors

fill(plotEMA5,plotEMA1, color=ema_fill_color,display = showemafill ? display.all : display.none)


This script gives you option to select whether to display OR hide 'EMA', 'BB' and the backfill of EMA based on the market trend.
